# Prove that either $A=\Delta B$ or $A=\Delta C$

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $(A,+)$ is an abelian group and that $A=B \cup C$. Define for any $X \subseteq A$ the following

$$\Delta X = \{ x_1-x_2  ; x_1 , x_2 \in X \}$$

Show that, if $B$ and $C$ have non-empty intersection, then either $A=\Delta B$ or $A=\Delta C$.

This problem has challenged me. My approach is elementary, I am taking $x \in B \cap C$ and trying to write any $a \in A$ as $a + kx - kx$ where $k$ is some integer such that $a-kx \in B$ (or $C$) and $kx$ also in $B$ (or $C$). The problem is, this may not happen, I can have (almost) every multiple of $x$ in $C \setminus B$ and every $a+kx$ in $B \setminus C$ for example.

I have tried some contradiction arguments, but there are inevitably too many cases to consider (as far as I have tried). Can anyone offer some insight? Elementary hints (or solutions) are prefered (no quotients).

Comment: Can I ask what's the source of this problem?

Comment: I believe this is taken from the Iberoamerican Math Olympiad for universities (OIMU 2000).  I was using it to prepare some students.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the hypotheses $A = B \cup C$ and $B \cap C \ne \emptyset$ are unaffected if we replace $B, C$ by $-a + B, - a + C$, for some $a \in A$, while $\Delta B, \Delta C$ are unchanged. Choosing $a \in B \cap C$, then, we may assume $0 \in B \cap C$. This yields $B \subseteq \Delta B, C \subseteq \Delta C$.

If $\Delta B \ne A$, choose $a \in A \setminus \Delta B$. Then for all $b\in B$, we have $a + b \notin B$, so that $a + b \in C$. Note in particular that $a \in C$, either because $a \notin \Delta B \supseteq B$, or directly because $0 \in B$.

But then for all $b \in B$ we have $b = (a + b) - a \in \Delta C$, so that $B \subseteq \Delta C$. Thus $A = B \cup C \subseteq \Delta C$.

Comment: BTW, if you drop the assumption that $B \cap C \ne \emptyset$, you get a counterexample by taking $A$ to be an abelian group which has a subgroup $B$ of index $2$ (for instance an abelian group $A$ of order $4$ would do), and taking $C = A \setminus B$. In this case we have $\Delta B = \Delta C = B$.